# Adding h264ify addon to Firefox slowes down full screen 4K video playing

Tags: firefox, h264

Full screen 4K video playing on an external 4K TV was butter smooth on my Thinkpad X1 Extreme. However, the fan was noisy. So I installed this plugin. Then I could not watch 4K video. I uninstalled this plugin and watching the same videos no longer smooth. I uninstalled and reinstalled Firefox but this issue remains. Could you please help?

Answer (score 0):

First, let me point out, that there is no Hardware acceleration for video in Firefox for Linux at all, so there is no point to install any add-on offering such features.

Second, its not obvious that changes made add-on you installed in your Firefox setting, so most easy solution will be to reset your profile.

You can go at about:support address in adressbar and click on Refresh Firefox button which should reset your preferences to default and revert any pref changes you or add-on made.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need h264fy for Firefox. Rather set `media.mediasource.webm.enabled` to **false** in `about:config`

More info: https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=9331156